# How can I bind to a view re-render in Ember.js?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have some jQuery code which needs to be run when a view is rendered. For the initial render I can easily do

```
App.FooView = Ember.View.extend({
  didInsertElement: function() {
    console.log("the view was rendered");
    this.$().someStuff();
  }
});
```

but since the `someStuff()` method is manipulating properties of the view elements, I need to run it when the view is re-rendered due to data bindings, because it will lose the custom generated properties.

Comment: add this.$().someStuff() inside afterRender method instead of didInsertElement & let me know...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you would like to re-render the view when a certain attribute changes then what you want would look something like this:

```
App.FooView = Ember.View.extend({
    myProperty: 'This value might change',
    myPropertyChanged: function() {
        //Do some stuff here (maybe change the template) and call...
        this.rerender();
    }.observes('myProperty')
});
```

But if you are looking to only re-render the view after the view is created then you want something more like this:

```
App.FooView = Ember.View.extend({
    init: function() {
        this._super();
        //Do some stuff here (maybe change the template) and call...
        this.rerender();
    }
});
```

**SOURCE:** http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Akash's explanation, you would want to use the didInsertElement hook instead of the init hook to only re-render after the view is created. So it would look more like:

```
App.FooView = Ember.View.extend({
    didInsertElement: function() {
        this.rerender();
    }
});
```

Although, I'm not exactly sure why you'd need to rerender after the view has already rendered.